# Java datasource lookup inside function

Tags: java, datasource

So I have a webapp that runs in multiple environments. I had a bit of code to lookup the database connection information from context.xml, connect, run a query against a table valued function to return a string of properties for a given key, a string assigned earlier in code in a servlet file.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Context dbContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) dbContext.lookup("System");

//try to get db connection
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
//try to query the database for properties
String q = "SELECT property_string FROM system.list_all WHERE key = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(q);
stmt.setString(1, key);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();
String properties = rs.getString("property_string");
conn.close();
```

This worked fine.  Continuing developing the app, I determined I needed to do the same query elsewhere, so I added a return of properties, and made it a function called getProperties in a .java file of utility functions.  Tested it still worked, it did, and proceeded to write a second servlet and have it call the function.

Only, the second call fails. It insists there is no results in the ResultSet, even when I pass in the exact same String key.  So now I have two servlets who each declare an instance of the utility class, and call the same function with the same input, one call succeeds and returns properties, the other fails with no results.

Am I missing something with Context or DataSource? Why does one call work and not the other?

Comment: Debug it? Need more info to help you. Where is it going wrong/different on the side that doesn't work?

Comment: It insists there is no result in the ResultSet.  'The result set has no current row' if you want the exact error.  Same string being passed into the function in both cases.